# What is the difference between /var/mail/XXX and /var/spool/mail/XXX

Tags: linux, fhs

I look exactly the same :
[image]
But What makes me suprised is that they are  synchronous.
[image]

Comment: [This](http://lists.debian.org/lsb-spec/1999/01/msg00065.html) might help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/var/spool/mail` is a symbolic link to `/var/mail` on my Debian/Sid system:

```
 % ls -ld /var/mail /var/spool/mail
 drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail 4096 Dec 31 17:46 /var/mail
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 May 12  2011 /var/spool/mail -> ../mail
```

Comment: thx, /var/mail is a symbolic link to /var/spool/mail in RHEL 5

Comment: Gentoo also links `/var/mail` to `/var/spool/mail`.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is really a matter of preferences; meaning: whatever mail delivery daemon you have in use on your system can use either or.

More specifically, it's a mere matter of preference of options laid out by the FHS.

- http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARMAILUSERMAILBOXFILES
- http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARSPOOLAPPLICATIONSPOOLDATA

Typically, on more complex mail configurations, things like mail queue, deferred messages, etc are stored in a structure in /var/spool/, independent of /var/mail.

You can see /var/mail used separately from /var/spool/mail (AKA: not symlinked).
Local mail will end up in /var/mail - while SMTP daemon handling email for virtual mailboxes, etc will happen in /var/spool/mail